# Regex - use matching group

Tags: java, regex

I have written a regex

```
 0[\.\-/]0[\.\-/]0
```

to compare following patterns;

- 0.0.0
- 0-0-0
- 0/0/0

But it also matches

- 0.0-0

That I don't want. So is there any way to match the already matched sequence?

```
 0[\.\-/]0@10
```

Comment: Group the class definition and backreference it to assert the same in between character gets matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0([./-])0\\1(0)
```

You will have to use `group` and then `backreference` it using `\1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mG8kZ9/3

Comment: Not sure, but I think you're mixing your backslashes. If `\.`, then `\1` (raw pattern). If `\\.`, then `\\1` (Java string to be compiled into a pattern).

Comment: `[\\.\\-/]` can be simplified to `[-./]`.

Comment: I spent a week to make my own RE engine to support such kind of situations. I should have asked this question before wasting my effort.

Comment: @AmitGupta your own engine :O how do you do that...can you share something about it

Comment: yeah I wanted to make a regex with limited capability supporting at least this group matching feature. So it can be fast and I can use it in my some NLP project... Ahh pre mature optimization... lemme find out the way to share the code.

Comment: Main logic of [my code](http://paste.ofcode.org/duAjEDQLjJSsuPPnYsTWxK) . It's a single java class.

Comment: I have made it as open source project now https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/BooleanSequence

Comment: @AmitGupta Gr8...will have a look

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as your title says perfectly: groups. Also called captures. Plain parentheses will capture the submatches; backslash-with-number will refer to the captures in order.

```
0([\.\-/])0\{1}0
```

or

```
0([\.\-/])0\1[0]
```

(because `\10` is something else, so we need to use alternate syntaxes or delimit them properly). `\1` (or `\{1}`) refers to the content between the first open plain parenthesis (i.e. not `(?:...)`, not `(?=...)`, just `(...)`) and its matching closing one.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use groups like:
    (0.0.0)|(0/0/0)|(0-0-0)

Comment: I actually have more complex pattern. I simplified it while asking the question.